# Нормально ли публиковать стадии решения задачи в качестве отдельных ответов?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы

В очереди проверки встретился [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207826/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8/1208048#1208048).

> Всем спасибо, помог stdin/stdout, конечная конфигурация была выполнена
> с помощью дека и сишного ввода вывода.

Я не вполне понимаю, как поступать с такими ответами. Тут же не содержится решения вопроса? Перешел по ссылке, чтоб разобраться, и увидел что автор публикует стадии решения олимпиадной задачи в качестве отдельных ответов. Это нормально? Или стоит внести правку в его вопрос, а все его ответы, кроме предпоследнего с реализацией рекомендовать удалить?

Comment: Ответ нельзя закрыть. Можно только удалить.

Comment: @EOF Да, я про удалить. Исправил

Comment: Да там вообще 4 удаленных **якобы** ответа, а по сути - дополнения к вопросу...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Нет, не допустимо. Ответ на вопрос должен быть именно ответом, а не уточнением, ответом на ответ или чем-то ещё. Это основное отличие формата SO от формата форумов.

---

Что же до того, что делать - не понимаю какие сложности тут могли возникнуть.

Любые "промежуточные стадии" подлежат удалению со стандартным комментарием

> Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.

Последнее "спасибо" подлежит удалению со стандартным комментарием

> Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, отметьте лучший ответ как принятый (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Уже отредактировал тот вопрос, поставил тревоги, теперь будем ждать, пока удалят промежуточные стадии решения.

Comment: А кстати... как вот эти удаления инициировать? Только через тревогу? Опции "удалить" у ответов-то ведь нет...

Comment: @Harry один попался в очереди проверок, на остальные я поставил тревоги.

Comment: @Harry поставить им минус. При отрицательном рейтинге они попадут в очередь сообщений низкого качества, а там эта опция как раз есть.

Comment: @Harry _Опции "удалить" у ответов-то ведь нет_, есть, появляется после первого минуса и доступна участн. с >20к.

Comment: @0xdb кстати да, всё время забываю про неё